# Comparar enum en java

Tags: java

¿Cómo están?

Estoy haciendo un pequeño proyecto, pero estoy atorado en esta parte.

Uso un stringtokenizador para separar un archivo de texto y uso una clase `enum` para asignarle a los tokens el valor con expresiones regulares. Hasta ahí bien, pero necesito evaluar cuándo un valor ya está asignado y dar un mensaje en pantalla.

```
public enum Tipo1
    {
        funcion(1), String(2),
        sepgenero(3), entero(4),
        funciongenero(5), funcionartista(6),
        funcionfavorito(7), maximogenero(8),
        maximoartista(9), maximofavorito(10),
        validacion(11),gauss(12),
        salida(13),separtista(14),sepnombre(15),separador(16),salto(17),genero(18),artista(19),nombre(20),album(21), ;

        private int valor1;

        private Tipo1 (int valor1){

            this.valor1 = valor1;
        }


        public int getvalor1() {
            return valor1;


    }

    }

    archivos a=new archivos();
        String s1= a.leertxt("->.rock:.;.Stones;.;.paintitblack|.|.black,.,.");

        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s1,"[.]");{
            System.out.println("SEMANTICO");
            while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {

              String jugador= st.nextToken();
              ArrayList<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();
              Scanner tokenize = new Scanner(jugador);

              while (tokenize.hasNext()) {
                 tokens.add(tokenize.next());


            System.out.println(tokens);

                Map<Sintactico.Tipo1, String> treeMap = new TreeMap<Sintactico.Tipo1, String>();
                    treeMap.put(Tipo1.funcion, "[->]+");
                    treeMap.put(Tipo1.genero, "[a-zA-Z\\s]+[:]+");
                    treeMap.put(Tipo1.artista, "[a-zA-Z\\s]+[;]");
                    treeMap.put(Tipo1.nombre, "[a-zA-Z\\s]+[|]");
                    treeMap.put(Tipo1.album, "[a-zA-Z\\s]+[,]");
                    treeMap.put(Tipo1.sepgenero, "[:]+");
                    treeMap.put(Tipo1.separtista, "[;]+");
                    treeMap.put(Tipo1.sepnombre, "[|]+");
                    treeMap.put(Tipo1.separador, "[,]+");
                    treeMap.put(Tipo1.entero, "[0-9]+");
                    treeMap.put(Tipo1.funciongenero, "[!Genero]+");
                    treeMap.put(Tipo1.funcionartista, "[!Artista]+");
                    treeMap.put(Tipo1.funcionfavorito, "[!Favorito]+");
                    treeMap.put(Tipo1.maximogenero, "[~Genero]+");
                    treeMap.put(Tipo1.maximoartista, "[~Artista]+");
                    treeMap.put(Tipo1.maximofavorito, "[~Favorito]+");
                    treeMap.put(Tipo1.validacion, "[>>+[¶]+]+");
                    treeMap.put(Tipo1.gauss, "[+]+");
                    treeMap.put(Tipo1.salida, "[<-]+");
                    treeMap.put(Tipo1.salto, "[\\s]+");
                    Iterator<Tipo1> it = treeMap.keySet().iterator();

                for(Tipo1 t:treeMap.keySet()){
                        String cr=treeMap.get(t);
                        String cr1=treeMap.get(Tipo1.artista);
                        Tipo1 key = it.next();


                        if(jugador.matches(cr)){
                            System.out.println(key);
                            }
            }
```

Y este es el resultado:

```
SEMANTICO
[->]
funcion
[rock:]
genero
[;]
separtista
lleva
[Stones;]
artista
[;]
separtista
lleva
[paintitblack|]
nombre
[|]
sepnombre
[black,]
album
[,]
separador
```

¿Cómo hago para evaluar cuando aparece más de un separador por ejemplo ;?

Agradezco algún consejo.

Comment: Si quieres que nos esforcemos en ayudarte, entonces esfuerzate en formatear el código, (cualquier IDE te permite hacerlo), es muy  penoso de leer.

Answer (score 1):

Yo creo que no tienes nada claro las cosas. Voy por partes, según mi opinión.
Utilizar *StringTokenizer* tiene el sentido de utilizar un mecanismo para extraer trozos de un String en funcion de un **delimitador**. Por ejemplo si tenemos un fichero de datos de la siguiente forma:

```
//ID;NOMBRE;EMAIL;URL
1000;PEPE;pepe@gmail.com;www.google.es
1001;DAVID;david@gmail.com;www.marca.es
.....
```

Cada fila tiene una estructura de campos delimitados por el caracter ";". Además sabemos que el primer trozo es el ID, el segundo NOMBRE, el tercero EMAIL y el cuarto una URL.

Por lo que he podido entender, tu deseas definir un *Map* en el que asocies una expresión regular para validar un campo en función de un *enum* que lo identifique

Existe en Java una clase denominada *EnumMap* que puede ayudarte mucho, defino mi *enum*:

```
public enum TipoRegex {
  ID(1,"[0-9]{1,9}(\.[0-9]{0,2})?$"),
  NOMBRE(2,"[a-zA-ZñÑ\s]{2,50}"),
  EMAIL(3,"w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"),
  URL(4,"^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \?=.-]*)*\/?$");

  public TipoRegex(int posicion,String regex) {
    this.posicion=posiscion;
    this.regex=regex;
  }

  public int getPosicion() {
    return posicion;
  }

  public String getRegex() {
    return regex;
  }

  private int posicion;
  private String regex;

}
```

Y ahora uso *EnumMap*:

```
EnumMap<TipoRegex,Pattern> regexMap=new EnumMap<TipoRegex,Pattern>(TipoRegex.class);
regexMap.put(TipoRegex.ID,createPattern(TipoRegex.ID));
regexMap.put(TipoRegex.NOMBRE,createPattern(TipoRegex.NOMBRE));
regexMap.put(TipoRegex.EMAIL,createPattern(TipoRegex.EMAIL));
regexMap.put(TipoRegex.URL,createPattern(TipoRegex.URL));
```

Defino el método para crear los Pattern adecuados:

```
private Pattern createPattern(TipoRegex tipo) {
  return Pattern.compile(tipo.getRegex());
}
```

Por último, solo queda leer el fichero y aplicar las validaciones donde corresponda:

```
String[] datos=getLineaFichero().split(";");
for(int index=0;index<datos.length;index ++) {
  if(index==0) {
    if(!regexMap.get(TipoRegex.ID).matches(datos[index]))( {
      //hacer lo que sea por ser un valor no valido
    }
  }
  if(index==1) {
    if(!regexMap.get(TipoRegex.NOMBRE).matches(datos[index]))( {
      //hacer lo que sea por ser un valor no valido
    }
  }
  if(index==2) {
    if(!regexMap.get(TipoRegex.EMAIL).matches(datos[index]))( {
      //hacer lo que sea por ser un valor no valido
    }
  }
  if(index==3) {
    if(!regexMap.get(TipoRegex.URL).matches(datos[index]))( {
      //hacer lo que sea por ser un valor no valido
    }
  }

}
```

Adaptado a tu código. Si desconoces el número de campos que viene en cada línea del fichero entonces si tiene sentido utilizar *StringTokenizer*. Si además deseas detectar el dato que es en función de la expresión regular **tendrás que estar seguro que ningún campo cumple dos expresiones regulares** y además tendrás que implementar un método que aplique todas las expresiones regulares hasta que encuentre la que le corresponde.